# about ParseObject.toJSON's Array handling with push notification

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform, push-notification, unityscript

I have a column with type 'Array' in my Parse.Object, and the content of it is:

```
"turns":[{"cracker121430062149839":825,"cracker71430058660979":675},   
{"cracker121430062149839":825,"cracker71430058660979":825}]
```

Then I send a push notification to specific users with this object. At the client side(Unity RemoteNotification.userInfo), I output the received data and the above content becomes:

```
"turns":[{"cracker71430058660979":2448103162259702435,"cracker121430062149839":2448103162259702585}, 
{"cracker71430058660979":2448103162259702585,"cracker121430062149839":2448103162259702585}]
```

My guess is that Parse treats the numbers as double, Unity treats them as System.Int64. What's exactly the behaviour at both Parse and Unity sides?

Answer (score 0):

It is a Unity json parser bug. I have the same problem in Unity 4.6.4.
Try to use:

```
long longNum;
int in32Num = ((int)(((longNum << 32) >> 32)));
```

Comment: Sorry for my English)